# Using Shaders for heavy calculation

Tags: unity-game-engine, vertex, vertex-shader, compute-shader

Almost all tutorials on the Net, teaching Shaders for different texture or distorting view. But I want to use it for other purpose. In each frame I have about 1000 objects that I want to do below calculation on each of them:

```
        for (int i=0; i<planeRotation.Count; i++) {
        oc =new Plane (new Vector3 (0, 0, 0),new Vector3 (0, 0, -1),new Vector3 (0, 1, 0));
        Quaternion Qangle = Quaternion.AngleAxis (planeRotation [i], new Vector3 (0f, 1.0f, 0f));
        occluder.normal = Qangle * originalPlaneNormal;
        List<C_Object> side1 = new List<C_Object> ();
        for (int c=0; c<c_object.Count; c++) {
            if (oc.GetSide c_object[c].Position-this.Position))
                side1.Add (c_object[c]);
        }

    }
```

But the problem is I don't know how can I implement it as a shader! I know it should be in a compute shader but I couldn't find a very simple example. it would be great for me if you show me how can I do this simple calculation on given input arrays.

Thank you.